# HTML, CSS and JS Boilerplate using Webpack, Babel, Sass and BrowserSync

Tags: webpack, babeljs, browser-sync

I am working on a html, css and js boilerplate for my projects. My goal is to have a setup where I can fire off `npm run watch` and all files are watched and compiled. It also should transpile and polypill the javascript.

Actually I kind of got what I wanted. But what I don't like, is that the CSS now gets injected in the index.html in a `<style>` tag at the top of the document. But this index.html with the injected CSS is not compiled, it's just presented by the live server.

Any ideas on how compile the CSS in it's own file? Besides that, has anybody any further tips for a such a boilerplate?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-babel-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.5",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "extract-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin')


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ["./_assets/js/src/index.js", "./_assets/css/sass/style.sass"]
  },
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./_assets/js/dist/"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: ["bundle.js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
        }
      }
    },
    {
            test: /\.sass$/,
      use: [
        "style-loader", 
        "css-loader", 
        "sass-loader" 
        ]
            },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            attrs: [':data-src']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true,
  plugins: [
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({

      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,
      server: { baseDir: ['./'] }
    })
  ]
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
            "useBuiltIns": "entry",
            "debug": true
        }]
    ]
 }
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'autoprefixer': {}
    }
}
```

**./_assets/js/src/index.js**

```
import './../../css/sass/style.sass';
import './../../../index.html';

require("@babel/polyfill");
require("./test.js")
require("./onPageLoad.js")
require("./onScroll.js")


// Testing if polyfill is working, since forEach doesnt work in some browsers
let testArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
testArray.forEach( item => {
  alert(item);
});

// Testing live reload
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0])
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using webpack4, try using the mini-css-extract-plugin to compile the css into its own file: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin.

> It creates a CSS file per JS file which contains CSS.

Older versions of webpack you can use extract-text-webpack-plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 0):

sample here for modern and legacy browser from the Darvin Webpack HTML Boilerplate:

```js
// snippet from https://github.com/unic/darvin-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack/settings/style-sass/index.js

const dev = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {
            hot: true,
            reloadAll: false
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            importLoaders: 2,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            plugins: () => [
              autoprefixer({
                grid: 'autoplace',
                flexbox: 'no-2009'
              })
            ],
            sourceMap: false,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            prependData: '$env: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ';',
            webpackImporter: false,
          }
        },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new StyleLintPlugin({
      context: 'src',
      configFile: '.stylelintrc',
      files: '**/*.scss',
      failOnError: false,
      quiet: false,
      syntax: 'scss'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: outputDir
    }),
  ]
};
```

and here's the setting for legacy browsers if you work with css vars:

```js
// https://github.com/unic/darvin-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack/settings/style-legacy/index.js

const prod = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: false,
            importLoaders: 2,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            plugins: () => [
              autoprefixer({
                grid: 'autoplace',
                flexbox: 'no-2009'
              }),
              require('postcss-css-variables')({ preserve : false, preserveAtRulesOrder: true })
            ],
            sourceMap: false,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            prependData: '$env: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ';',
            webpackImporter: false,
          }
        },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
```